# How to open file in python?

Tags: python

Iam coding in vs code with python3.
in the tutorial says that you should write
`f=open("filename.txt")`
and then run it and if you want to read it
`f=open("filename.txt","r")`
and I write a txt in my computre and I'm sure its exicts in my loptop but every time I run the code it gives me :`(FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory)`
what should I do?

Comment: did you try to read file from absolute path?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change `"filename.txt"` for the absolute path of that file. That means you should go to your file and copy the exact complete path from the storage through all directories until reaching it:

```
f=open("filename.txt","r")
f=open(r"C:\\Users\\your_user\\Desktop\\filename.txt","r") #Example of an absolute path, in this case the file is in Desktop but you have to copy the exact path you have
```

If that doesn't work, the file might be corrupted or defective, so you would have to try other solutions.

Comment: In order to use back slashes, you need to escape them, like so:- `"\\"`.